# how to sign a multiple output transaction

Tags: raw-transaction, bitcore, javascript

currently i m using below code,how to add multiple address to address.

```
let transaction = new bitcore.Transaction()
            transaction
                .from(txoSet)
                .to( userAddress, amountTotransfer)
                .fee(10000)
                .change(changeAddress)
                .sign(BTCkey)
            var sendTx = script.broadcastTransaction(transaction.serialize())
            sendTx.then(async function (tx) {
                console.log('tx', tx);
                })
```

Comment: any one please guide

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just call `to` multiple times:

```
            .from(txoSet)
            .to( userAddress, amountTotransfer)
            .to( userAddress2, amountTotransfer2)
            .fee(10000)
```